# Select a subset of lidar tiles (las files)

Tags: lidar, lidr

I have terrestrial lidar scans that were merged and tiled into 100 x 100m tiles, but they are a little too big so I re-tiled to 50x50m. However, a lot of tiles at the edge of the study area are very small and do not contain useful information (e.g., 10x10m) which causes problems in my processing pipeline.

How can I select a subset of tiles from the las catalog picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `lidR` you can filter the tiles with a low area

```r
ctg = readLAScatalog(...)
area = (ctg$Max.X - ctg$Min.X) * (ctg$Max.Y - ctg$Min.Y)
bigtiles = ctg[area > 100000,]
```

Answer (score 0):

`catalog_select` from the `lidR` package allows individual las catalog tiles to be selected using the cursor.

e.g.

```
ctg <- readLAScatalog(...)
ctg_new <- catalog_select(ctg)
```

[image]